# Parse big xml file in android

Tags: android

In my application there is a search option. If the user enters a search value, I have to get a value from the webservice. I am getting a large webservice value. In my webservice string values are coming. I am getting like <> like xml character entity reference like. I want to replace all characters and parse xml. Can anybody tell me how to do this and give an example?

I tried with `StringBuffer` for unescapexml character, I am getting out of memory error

```
public  String unescapeXML(String str) {
        if (str == null || str.length() == 0)
          return "";

        StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
        int len = str.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
          char c = str.charAt(i);
          if (c == '&') {
            int pos = str.indexOf(";", i);
            if (pos == -1) { // Really evil
              buf.append('&');
            } else if (str.charAt(i + 1) == '#') {
              int val = Integer.parseInt(str.substring(i + 2, pos), 16);
              buf.append((char) val);
              i = pos;
            } else {
              String substr = str.substring(i, pos + 1);
              if (substr.equals("&amp;"))
                buf.append('&');
              else if (substr.equals("&lt;"))
                buf.append('<');
              else if (substr.equals("&gt;"))
                buf.append('>');
              else if (substr.equals("&quot;"))
                buf.append('"');
              else if (substr.equals("&apos;"))
                buf.append('\'');
              else if (substr.equals("&nbsp;"))
                  buf.append(" ");

              else
                // ????
                buf.append(substr);
              i = pos;
            }
          } else {
            buf.append(c);
          }
        }
        return buf.toString();
      }
```

I tried with stream, I am not able to do it. Can anybody give an example how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

You should not parse it on your own. There are better ways - SAX or DOM.
This resource contains a lot of useful inforamtion about these both ways (and code examples too): http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2002/06/26/xml.html

Comment: Do you mean, "should **not** parse it on your own"?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here in order to get more details about android included parsers :

http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/parsers/package-summary.html

But make your own parser with SAX is probably the best choice in your case ;)